# overflow-x prevent overflow-y visibility for ::after

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to display a little cross ("X") at the top right of a `div` by using the pseudo-element `::after`. All my `div` are in a carrousel with the property `overflow-x: auto` but now the cross is cropped when passing the top of the `div`.

What I obtain :
[X is cropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvOKD.png)

What I want :
[X is visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nphNC.png)

I tried all the values of overflow-y to make the X visible, without success. And I need the `overflow-x: auto` because I can have a lot or a little to display.

Demonstration code :

```css
.container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: visible; /* Whatever value is used, it doesn't change anything */
}

.content {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    position: relative
}
.content::after {
    content: "X";
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a good question. It works when removing all the `overflow` rules, but it seems that adding `overflow-x: auto;` causes overflow in the y axis to be hidden. Weird.